# Magento: curl_setopt_array() error

Tags: magento-1.9, curl

I downgrade php7 to php 5.6,now my magento site not working its getting error

```
     ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_setopt_array() in /var/www/html/rmcstore/lib/Varien/Http/Adapter/Curl.php on line 77.
```

How to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CURL is not installed on your server, check your `phpinfo()` for CURL.

If not present, you or your provider can enable it in the PHP config.

Comment: how to enable it

Comment: For enabling CURL in PHP (PHP.ini, WAMP, XAMPP, Ubuntu), Please check it http://www.tomjepson.co.uk/enabling-curl-in-php-php-ini-wamp-xamp-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

Seems there's no curl installed on your server. Check your `phpinfo()` for curl. If not present, you or your provider can enable it in the PHP config:

`/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` (or similar)

enable extension:

```
extension=curl.so
```